# What is the type of *args, *kwargs and **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, arguments, variadic-functions

When printing `args` and `kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args) # Here
    print(kwargs) # Here

nums = (1, 2, 3, 4)
person = { 
    "name": "John",
    "age": 27,
}
        
test(*nums, **person)
```

A tuple and a dictionary are printed:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
{'name': 'John', 'age': 27}
```

And, when printing `*args` and `*kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args) # Here
    print(*kwargs) # Here

# ...
```

4 numbers and 2 keys are printed:

```py
1 2 3 4
name age
```

But, when printing `**kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(**kwargs) # Here

# ...
```

The error occurs:

> TypeError: 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Now, when printing the type of `args` and `kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(args)) # Here
    print(type(kwargs)) # Here

# ...
```

`'tuple'` and `'dict'` are printed:

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
```

But, when printing the type of `*args`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(*args)) # Here

# ...
```

And when printing the type of `*kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(*kwargs)) # Here

# ...
```

And when printing the type of `**kwargs`:

```py
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(**kwargs)) # Here

# ...
```

The error occurs:

> TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments

So now, what is the type of `*args`, `*kwargs` and `**kwargs`? or don't they have type?

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` are **not values at all**, so no they don't have types. When used in a function call they're _syntax_ for passing sequences and mappings as positional and keyword arguments respectively.

Comment: `args` is a `list[T]` while `kwargs` is a `dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: `*` is an _operator_ to _spread_ the arguments of an iterable.  The same applies to `**` but for mappings.

Comment: No, `args` is a tuple, and not necessarily a homogenous one. `*` and `**` are not operators here, but parts of the `def` statement syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`*args` and `**kwargs` are not expressions, and thus have no type; they are part of the syntax of a `def` statement. Note that the *names* are arbitrary; it's the act of prefixing them with `*` or `**` that produces special behavior.

`*args` captures all positional arguments not assigned to positional parameters to a single tuple, meaning `args` has type `tuple`. (Because the arguments only appear at runtime, there is no more specific static type for `args`; `tuple` and `tuple[Any, ...]` are equivalent.)

`**kwargs` captures all keyword arguments not assigned to other parameters in a single `dict`, meaning `kwargs` has type `dict[str, Any]`. (We don't know what the *values* might be before running the code, but it is guaranteed that the keys are the strings representing the keywords.)

The same syntax is used in the context of *calling* a function as well. Any iterable can be prefixed with a `*` to pass each element of the iterable as a separate positional argument, rather than passing the entire iterable as a single argument. Any mapping with strings as keys can be prefixed with `**` to pass each key/value pair as a separate keyword argument, rather than passing the entire mapping as a single positional argument.

---

I say *mapping* and not `dict` because while `dict` is the only *built-in* type that supports the mapping protocol, you can always implement your own type that satisfies it. Here's a trivial, nonsensical, but valid, mapping type:

```
import collections.abc

class NotADict(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return f'value: {k}'

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from ['a', 'b', 'c']

    def __len__(self):
        return 3

def foo(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

Then

```
d = NotADict()
foo(**d)
```

outputs `{'a': 'value: a', 'b': 'value: b', 'c': 'value: c'}`. Basically, a `dict` using something like `{k: d[k] for k in d}`, as `NotADict` supports both iteration and indexing, and that dict is assigned to `kwargs`.